# Java block without an associated keyword

Tags: java, syntax, scope, braces

Out of curiosity I tried this out to see if it was valid code inside a method:

```
{
    // code
}
```

And it is! All it does is limit the scope:

```
{
    int i = 1;
}

i = 2; // error
```

This is nice for e.g. when I've needed to do something that looks structurally like this:

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < number; i++) {...}

doSomethingWithTheCount(i);
```

But I'd like to limit the scope of `i`:

```
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < number; i++) {...}

    doSomethingWithTheCount(i);
}
```

And indeed I can. Is this useful for anything else or just obscure?

Additionally, I've read that limiting the scope of an object is a good way to ensure it is garbage collected sooner so potentially doing this is beneficial in that regard. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes this is really useful and I often use it when cutting and pasting test code.  But what is the question?

Comment: @user2310289 Whether it is harmful somehow, viewed as disorganized or makes code less readable.

Comment: If it does not make any difference to the compiler and your logic, and if it improves readabilty and scope, then it must be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong in declaring anonymous blocks, so you don't have to worry about it as such. Some people may have opinions about it following Java coding conventions or other ideas of a more or less aesthetic nature, but that's subjective and up to you to decide the validity of. I, on my hand, would have no such issues with it.

However, it is not correct that it helps garbage collection. In the compiled bytecode, the local variables persist beyond the end of the block's scope and will retain their values unless you explicitly clear them to `null`; the block only affects symbol allocation in the Java source, and does not translate to anything that the JVM sees.

Additionally, it may be worth noting that you can also use these kinds of blocks for control-flow purposes, like this:

```
foo: {
    /* ... */
    if(bar)
        break foo;
    /* ... */
}
```

Unfortunately, Java does not support `continue foo` for custom looping logic. :(

Comment: That's interesting the scope has no effect except in source. Also the labeled break seems pretty handy. I've wanted to do that a lot of times. If only I'd known.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* limit scope like this if you really feel the need, but the compiler trivially detects that your variable will not be used again before the end of the method and will reuse its memory or register location if it's convenient.

Regarding your edit about GC, (1) `int`s aren't GCd, (2) I would bet that once the compiler detects the end of a variable's use within its scope, it marks the scope as over for purposes of GC, and (3) if you are burning so much memory in a single function that this becomes a concern, you're doing it wrong.

Unless there's a compelling reason for explicitly limiting scope like this, and I don't see a good one, I would recommend against it. If nothing else, it's rarely used and so could confuse other programmers/later maintainers, either if they (like you) hadn't seen it before or if they couldn't figure out why you did it.

Comment: That is a good point that you can simply null in the case of objects. I guess the scope issue just bugs me for some reason. It seems disorganized to me both ways. Really I just want a for loop that includes its own termination block.

Answer (score 0):

In Java (unlike C) you are allowed to declare the variable inside the for loop if you are worried about scope.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    //Do Something
}
```

For the while loop, you can always change it to a Do-While if you are worried about the variable living outside the scope of the method.

Example:

```
do {
    int i = 0;
    //Do Something

    i++;
} while (i < number);
```

Comment: I see no reason why you can't/shouldn't do what you had. Personally, I would execute the while loop in the same method, but would change the for loop to reflect what I have.

Comment: Yes but sometimes you have to do something with the variable after the loop. In this case it means the variable continues to live until the end of the outer scope.

Comment: If the variable is going to be used after the loop, then absolutely execute what you had. There isn't anything wrong with it.